# Python on Zapier issue

Tags: python, zapier

Any Ideas what I am doing wrong it won't run!

[image]

Comment: Typo: You're calling a function with square brackets instead of parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget your `:` at the end of your if statement!